# Pandas' EMA not matching the stock's EMA?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, finance, stockquotes

I am trying to use Python (with Pandas) to calculate the 20-day Exponential Moving Averages (EMA) of daily stock data for Intel (INTC). Pandas has a number of ways of doing this, and I've also tried stockstats, which runs on Pandas, but they never return the same EMA as I get from stock/finance websites.

I've double checked the close prices, and they match, but the EMA always comes out "wrong".

This is the CSV I'm using: [INTC Stock Data](https://pastebin.com/f8F2Jgdh)

It contains the daily Date, Month Name, Open, High, Low, Close, Day Avg, and Volume for Intel's stock (Ticker: INTC) from 4/20/2016 to 2/1/2018.

When I look to the bigger stock websites like [MarketWatch](https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/intc/charts) or [Fidelity](https://eresearch.fidelity.com/eresearch/evaluate/snapshot.jhtml?symbols=intc), their numbers don't match mine. They match *each other*, but not me.

For example...

```
df2['Close'].ewm(span=20,min_periods=0,adjust=False,ignore_na=False).mean()
```

or...

```
df2['Close'].ewm(span=20, min_periods=20, adjust=True).mean()
```

or...

```
df2["Close"].shift().fillna(df["Close"]).ewm(com=1, adjust=False).mean()
```

Give me EMA's for 2/1/2018 like $44.71, $47.65, $46.15, etc. when the *real 20-Day EMA* on *any* finance site is $45.65. And I get the wrong numbers no matter what date I try to compute the EMA for. It's even wrong when I just try for 5-Day EMAs.

I've read, watched and followed tutorials on the subject, but their results also don't match the accepted/published EMA's you'd find on any finance site. The people creating the tutorials and videos simply never check them against each other after Panda's crunches the numbers. And I need my numbers to match.

How do I arrive at the same figures every other finance site on the internet is getting for EMAs? I don't think this has anything to do with adjusted close prices because I'm using old/settled data and my close prices and dates are the same as theirs.

Comment: Have you tried `ewma`?

Comment: @BUZZY It's deprecated in favor of ewm, but yes I have tried it with no better results.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Sort the DataFrame so that the dates are in increasing order. 
Since your data is in decreasing order by date, if you don't sort the dates first, your `ewm` calculation exponentially weights the *earliest* dates the most, rather than the latest date (as it should be).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('intc_data.txt', parse_dates=['Date'], index_col=['Date'])
df['backward_ewm'] = df['Close'].ewm(span=20,min_periods=0,adjust=False,ignore_na=False).mean()
df = df.sort_index()
df['ewm'] = df['Close'].ewm(span=20,min_periods=0,adjust=False,ignore_na=False).mean()
print(df[['ewm', 'backward_ewm']].tail())
```

yields

```
                  ewm  backward_ewm
Date                               
2018-01-26  45.370936     48.205638
2018-01-29  45.809895     48.008337
2018-01-30  46.093714     47.800794
2018-01-31  46.288599     47.696667
2018-02-01  46.418256     47.650000
```

This agrees with [Marketwatch](https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/intc/charts) which says the EWMA(20) on 2018-02-01 was 46.42.

[image]

Comment: You are a damned wizard :) This works like a charm, thank you SO much! I'm still learning Pandas (as I'm sure you guessed). Cheers!

Answer (score 9):

I suggest using [Pandas TA](https://github.com/twopirllc/pandas-ta) to calculate technical indicators in python. I find it more accurate and has many more indicators than the ones that come with pandas.

Using Pandas TA, the 20 period exponential moving average is calculated like:

```
import pandas_ta as ta

data["EMA20"] = ta.ema(df2["Close"], length=20)
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use EMA, you need more data, such as to compute EMA (period = 14), you need at least 28 K line data
Below I provide OKX ETH - USDT - SWAP - 1 h to do the test,In the code to use limit = 14 is wrong,Limit effect is right = 100:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
import time

#Data:OKX ETH-USDT-SWAP 1H
limit= 20 #When using limit = 100 data is normal
url = 'https://www.okx.com/api/v5/market/candles?instId=ETH-USDT-SWAP&bar=1H&limit={}'.format(limit)    
headers={'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36'}
result =requests.get(url=url,headers=headers).json()
df=pd.DataFrame(result['data'])
df = df.rename(columns={0: 'open_time', 1: 'open', 2: 'high', 3: 'low',  4: 'close', 5: 'volz',6:'voleth',7:'volusdt',8:'KlineState'})
for i in list(df):
    df[i]=list(reversed(df[i]))   


#Pandas ema14 example:
'''
DataFrame.ewm(com=None, span=None, halflife=None, alpha=None, min_periods=0, adjust=True, ignore_na=False, 
axis=0, times=None, method='single')[source]
'''
period=14
while True:
    example_ema_1=df['close'].ewm(span=period).mean().values[-1].round(2)

    example_ema_2=df['close'].ewm(span=period, adjust=False).mean().values[-1].round(2)

    example_ema_3=df['close'].ewm(span=period, adjust=False,ignore_na=True).mean().values[-1].round(2)

    print('example_ema_1',example_ema_1)
    print('example_ema_2',example_ema_2)
    print('example_ema_3',example_ema_3)

    time.sleep(1)
```